Opensearch default tenant per role
Is it possible to set default tenant for a specific role in Opensearch? It is quite annoying that each time user needs to select the appropriate one.
I know that I can set a default tenant for all users in Management->Security->Tenants. However I have multiple roles and some users don't have access to the default one and it opens Global one for them instead.
